# How to apply a function ( BigramCollocationFinder) to Pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, numpy, pandas, machine-learning, nltk

i am not very used to programming and need some help to solve a problem. 
I have a .csv with 4 columns and about 5k rows, filled with questions and answers.
I want to find word collocations in each cell.

Starting point: Pandas dataframe with 4 columns and about 5k rows. (Id, Title, Body, Body2)

Goal: Dataframe with 7 columns (Id, Title, Title-Collocations, Body, Body_Collocations, Body2, Body2-Collocations) and applied a function on each of its rows.

I have found an example for Bigramm Collocation in the NLTK Documentation.

```
bigram_measures = nltk.collocations.BigramAssocMeasures()
finder.apply_freq_filter(3)
finder = BigramCollocationFinder.from_words(nltk.corpus.genesis.words('english-web.txt'))
print (finder.nbest(bigram_measures.pmi, 5))
>>>[('Beer', 'Lahai'), ('Lahai', 'Roi'), ('gray', 'hairs'), ('Most', 'High'), ('ewe', 'lambs')]
```

I want to adapt this function to my Pandas Dataframe. I am aware of the apply function for Pandas Dataframes, but can't manage to get it work.

This is my test-approach for one of the columns:

```
df['Body-Collocation'] = df.apply(lambda df: BigramCollocationFinder.from_words(df['Body']),axis=1)
```

but if i print that out for an example row i get

```
print (df['Body-Collocation'][1])
>>> <nltk.collocations.BigramCollocationFinder object at 0x113c47ef0>
```

I am not even sure if this is the right way. Can someone point me to the right direction?

Comment: You could print the variables of your lambda function in order to find out if it  is in the proper format for your function. Maybe you have to do something like 'x.values'

Comment: Can you add [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Comment: I will keep that in mind for the next time and edit this later. Thx everybody.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to apply `BigramCollocationFinder.from_words()` to each `value` in the `Body` `column, you'd have to do:

```
df['Body-Collocation'] = df.Body.apply(lambda x: BigramCollocationFinder.from_words(x))
```

In essence, `apply` allows you to loop through the `rows` and provide the corresponding `value` of the `Body` `column` to the applied function.

But as suggested in the comments, providing a data sample would make it easier to address your specific case.

Answer (score 3):

Thx, for the answer. I guess the question i asked was not perfectly phrased. But your answer still helped me to find a solution. Sometimes its good to take a short break :-)

If someone is interested in the answer. This worked out for me.

```
df['Body-Collocation'] = df.apply(lambda df: BigramCollocationFinder.from_words(df['Question-Tok']),axis=1)
df['Body-Collocation'] = df['Body-Collocation'].apply(lambda df: df.nbest(bigram_measures.pmi, 3))
```